# No me muestra la fecha que introduje

Tags: python-3.8

El objetivo del código es introducir una fecha y que me la vuelva a mostrar si es que todo esta bien o que me devuelva none en caso no lo este. Pero cada valor de fecha que introduzco solo me muestra none, las 2 primeras funciones estan bien pero la tercera es la que me esta errando.

```py
def isYearLeap(year):
    if year%400==0:
        return True 
    else:
        if year%4==0 and year%100!=0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def daysInMonth(year, month):
    i=month
    d_31=[1,3,5,7,8,10,31]
    d_30=[4,6,9,11]

    if i in d_31:
        return 31
    elif i in d_30:
        return 30
    else:
        if isYearLeap(year)==True:
            return 29
        else:
            isYearLeap(year)==False
            return 28

def dayOfYear(year, month, day):

    if daysInMonth(year, month)==31:
        if day<=31:
            return 1
        
    elif daysInMonth(year, month)==30:
        if day<=30:
            return year,month,day
    
    elif daysInMonth(year, month)==28:
        if day<=28:
            return year,month,day
    
    elif daysInMonth(year, month)==29:
            if day<=29:
            return year,month,day

print(dayOfYear(2000, 2, 31))
```

Comment: tienes un error de sintaxis en `else: isYearLeap(year)==False` si vas a comprobar te falta un `if` y si vas a asignar solo es un `=` pero no tiene mucho sentido ya que es una función. Si pones un `if` también recuerda poner los 2 puntos `:`

Comment: Además, sabias que febrero del año 2000 solo tuvo 29 días? Ósea que tu programa funciona!, si solo tuvo 29 días, significa que con `print(dayOfYear(2000, 2, 29))` debería funcionar

Answer (score 2):

El código podría ser más legible reduciéndolo a un par de `if - else`, evaluando:

1. Si el día o mes son negativos, o si el año es [menor de
   1583](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%C3%B1o_bisiesto#Reforma_gregoriana) se mantendrá `False`
2. Si el día es menor o igual que la cantidad de días que debe tener el mes según la lista `md`, es `True`
3. Si es 29 de febrero y el año es divisible por 4 y (no es divisible por 100 pero si por 400), es `True`

```
def dayOfYear(year, month, day):
    result = False
    md = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    if day < 1 or month < 1 or year < 1583:
        pass
    elif day <= md[month-1]:
        result = True
    elif month == 2 and day == 29:
        if year%4 == 0 and (year%400 == 0 or year%100 != 0):
            result = True
    return (year, month, day) if result else False
```

Pruebas:

```
print(dayOfYear(2020, 2, 29))  # (2020, 2, 29)
print(dayOfYear(2020, 2, 30))  # False
print(dayOfYear(2020, 12, 30)) # (2020, 12, 30)
print(dayOfYear(2021, 2, 29))  # False
print(dayOfYear(2021, 7, 30))  # (2021, 7, 30)
print(dayOfYear(2020, 7, 31))  # (2020, 7, 31)
print(dayOfYear(2020, 7, -1))  # False
print(dayOfYear(2400, 2, 29))  # (2400, 2, 29)
```

Finalmente, la forma más rápida de resolver esto es con la librería integrada:

```
import datetime

def dayOfYear(year, month, day):
    try:
        _ = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
        result = True
    except:
        result = False
    return (year, month, day) if result else False
```